# Generate html section with other nested section every 4 iteration using twig template engine

Tags: php, loops, twig

I've the following query result:

```
     array(66) {
  [0]=>
  array(6) {
    ["numero"]=>
    int(548)
    ["coreo"]=>
    string(30) "Disco Dance Solo Female Junior"
    ["elementi"]=>
    int(1)
    ["club"]=>
    string(12) "Winning Club"
    ["nazione"]=>
    string(10) "San Marino"
    ["ballerini"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(2) {
        ["nome"]=>
        string(18) "Della Fera Alessia"
        ["sesso"]=>
        string(1) "F"
      }
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(6) {
    ["numero"]=>
    int(100)
    ["coreo"]=>
    string(30) "Disco Dance Solo Female Junior"
    ["elementi"]=>
    int(1)
    ["club"]=>
    string(12) "Winning Club"
    ["nazione"]=>
    string(10) "San Marino"
    ["ballerini"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(2) {
        ["nome"]=>
        string(19) "Spinelli Elisabetta"
        ["sesso"]=>
        string(1) "F"
      }
    }
  }
```

.
.
.

and so on...

My target is generate an html page like the follow using twig template engine:

```
<div style="height: 50%; width: 100%;">
    <article style="float: left;">
        <h4>{{numero}}</h4>
        <ul>
            <li>{{coreo}}</li>
            <li>{{club}}</li>
            <li>{{nazione}}</li>
            <li>{{elementi}}</li>
            <li>{{ballerini.nome}} - {{ballerini.sesso}}</li>
            <li>{{ballerini.nome}} - {{ballerini.sesso}}</li>
        </ul>
    </article>

    <article style="float: right;">
        <h4>{{numero}}</h4>
        <ul>
            <li>{{coreo}}</li>
            <li>{{club}}</li>
            <li>{{nazione}}</li>
            <li>{{elementi}}</li>
            <li>{{ballerini.nome}} - {{ballerini.sesso}}</li>
            <li>{{ballerini.nome}} - {{ballerini.sesso}}</li>
        </ul>
    </article>
</div>

<div style="height: 50%; width: 100%;">
    <article style="float: left;">
        <h4>{{numero}}</h4>
        <ul>
            <li>{{coreo}}</li>
            <li>{{club}}</li>
            <li>{{nazione}}</li>
            <li>{{elementi}}</li>
            <li>{{ballerini.nome}} - {{ballerini.sesso}}</li>
            <li>{{ballerini.nome}} - {{ballerini.sesso}}</li>
        </ul>
    </article>

    <article style="float: right;">
        <h4>{{numero}}</h4>
        <ul>
            <li>{{coreo}}</li>
            <li>{{club}}</li>
            <li>{{nazione}}</li>
            <li>{{elementi}}</li>
            <li>{{ballerini.nome}} - {{ballerini.sesso}}</li>
            <li>{{ballerini.nome}} - {{ballerini.sesso}}</li>
        </ul>
    </article>
</div>
```

in which create a section every 4 records.

I start with the following code

```
{% for i in 1..((numerinogruppo|length))|round(0,'ceil') %}
    {% if loop.index % 4 == 0 %}
        <section class="sheet padding-10mm">
            {% if loop.index % 2 == 0 %}
                <div style="height: 50%; width: 100%;">
                    <article style="float: left;">
                        <h4>{{ numeronogruppo[loop.index][numero] }}</h4>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Coreografia</li>
                            <li>Nazione</li>
                            <li>Eventuale ballerino 1</li>
                            <li>Eventuale ballerino 2</li>
                        </ul>
                    </article>

                    <article style="float: right;">
                        <h4>2</h4>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Coreografia</li>
                            <li>Nazione</li>
                            <li>Eventuale ballerino 1</li>
                            <li>Eventuale ballerino 2</li>
                        </ul>
                    </article>
                </div>

                <div style="height: 50%; width: 100%;">
                    <article style="float: left;">
                        <h4>1</h4>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Coreografia</li>
                            <li>Nazione</li>
                            <li>Eventuale ballerino 1</li>
                            <li>Eventuale ballerino 2</li>
                        </ul>
                    </article>

                    <article style="float: right;">
                        <h4>2</h4>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Coreografia</li>
                            <li>Nazione</li>
                            <li>Eventuale ballerino 1</li>
                            <li>Eventuale ballerino 2</li>
                        </ul>
                    </article>
                </div>
            {% endif %}
        </section>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

but I don't know how to access to the array value and display them in the for loop.
Any suggestions?
Thank you all.